# Display Images From Array

Tags: image, matlab

I just want to iterate through an image array one by one but I can't get it working, I get the errors below. I can show single images via imshow (a), but not iterate through an array.

Error using getImageFromFile (line 12)
Cannot find the specified file: "a".

Error in imageDisplayParseInputs (line 74)
    [common_args.CData,common_args.Map] = ...

Error in imshow (line 198)
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Code

```
% Images
a = 'redsquare.bmp';
b = 'bluesquare.bmp';
c = 'greysquare.bmp';
d = 'yellowsquare.bmp';

% Array to display
t = [a b c d];

% Loop to display    
for n=1:length(t)
 imshow(t(n))
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several bugs in the code as it is.
First, verify that the directory where the images are located is in Matlab's path , or try  adding the full path of the images locations. 
I'd recommend to use a **cell array** to contain all the file names. The way you've done it in the question is to concatenate all strings to one long one, that is

```
t =

redsquare.bmpbluesquare.bmpgreysquare.bmpyellowsquare.bmp
```

So in the code change `t` to:

```
t = {a, b, c, d}; % note the curly brackets
```

In the loop, you need first to read the image to an array before showing it, therefor add an `imread` line. After reading the file onto an array (lets called that array `im`), you can use `imshow` to plot it. All in all, the code in the loop should  be:

```
for n=1:numel(t)
   im=imread(t{n}); 
   imshow(im);
end
```

Again, note that I used curly brackets `{}` for the `imread` line, that is the way to extract the cell element content.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Is it possible to also retrieve just items 1-3? So rather than    n=1:nume1(t)  to use everything in the cell array, i'd like to just get the first three items.

Comment: Sure, just `for n=1:3` or `for n=[1 2 4]`, or `for n=[1 2 1 3 1 4]` etc. just keep in mind that these indices correspond to `a-d` filenames, you can arrange them to whatever you want...

Answer (score 0):

it is a while since i have done matlab so i am struggling to remember the syntax, however i am pretty sure that your problem is that a bitmap is made up of a 2 dimensional array, which you are putting into another array.

Therefore when you do t(1), your not getting the entire bitmap, just a single element.

Firstly try asking matlab for the shape of t. The syntax eludes me it has been some time. 
Then use the required syntax to extract the required 2-d matrix.

Hope this helps